# add a feature in openlayers using lonlat from geolocation

Tags: openlayers-2, geolocation

I'm trying to add a feature in a openlayer's vector layer using the lonlat that came from the HTML5's geolocation API.

Combining tutorials for the geolocation and this [demo](http://www.pediaphon.org/~bischoff/location_based_services/) I created the following code

```
<input type="button" value="Where Am I" onClick="loadDemo();" />


//this is outside the init() openlayers function. If i put it inside init(), will not work at all
function loadDemo() {
if(navigator.geolocation) {
document.getElementById("support").innerHTML = "I'll find you!";
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateLocation, handleLocationError, {timeout:100000});
} else {
document.getElementById("support").innerHTML = "Browser is so old";
}}

function updateLocation(position) {
var latitudeg = position.coords.latitude;
var longitudeg = position.coords.longitude;
var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = latitudeg;//works
document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = longitudeg;//works
document.getElementById("accuracy").innerHTML = "This location is accurate within " +accuracy + " meters."//works
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(longitudeg,latitudeg).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));//works
alert(lonLat);//works
var pointg = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLat);
var feature_point_g = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(pointg);
alert(pointg.lat);//not working, returns undifined
alert(feature_point_g);//not working, returns [object Object]
pins.addFeatures([feature_point_g]);//not working
pins.refresh({force:true});//not working
}
```

As you can see, problem is , there is something wrong with creating the point and the feature. Honestly, I searched and checked and can't solve this. Can you see something I don't?

Thanks

Comment: When I used your demo it created a point near my location. Can you describe more about what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: @ Taylor H. That's not my demo, I found it. Something goes wrong when creating the point and the feature. They return `undifined` and `[object Object]` respectively. So I can't add a simple feature to my layer, based on the lon/lat that succesfully came from geolocation API

Comment: By feature do you mean a shape from geoserver or mapserver, or like a simple picture such as a flag?

Comment: The best thing to do when you aren't sure what your javascript app is doing at certain points is to use console.log(). IF you aren't already using Google Chrome now is a good time to switch, because I think the developer tools are unmatched by any other browsers currently. Invoke the Console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J on Windows and insert console.log("Here is variable lonlat: "+lonlat) in your code and do that for a bunch of your variables to see what they are doing at certain points.

Answer (score 5):

You are passing an incorrect argument to the OpenLayers.Geometry.Point constructor. You don't need the lonLat. Try the following:

```
var pointg = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(longitudeg, latitudeg);
pointg.transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sir, you made my day. But, there is something strange going on. Features gets rendered on the map. But `alert(feature_point_g);` still alerts _[object Object]_ . In Chrome's console I can see there is actually a new feature added and as I said gets rendered. But why still alerts _object_ ?Is that normal? Thanks again.

Comment: yes, that's normal.  better to use Firebug or Chrome console and just output debug there with  `console.debug(myObject)` or console.log or console.warn depending on what's happening.  Alert essentially runs yourobject.`toString()` in the background to convert `Object` to a `String`.